# Iterate over files in directory, create folders based on file names and move files into respective folders

Tags: command-line, bash

I would like to move files in a directory into folders with the same names.  I would like to do all this using the command line or a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

for  f in $1; do
  mv "$f".* <not sure what do do>
done
```

How can I grab the names of the files and create the folders?

Comment: So for example  you have `file1.txt` `file2.txt` `file3.txt` , and you want to take `file1.txt` and move to folder `file1`, `file2.txt` to folder `file2`. What if we have duplicate names like `file2.jpg` ? also move to `file2` folder ?

Comment: yes exactly.  Duplicates can be moved to the same folder.

Comment: @MichaelJames Unlikely (impossibly) duplicate names exist in a (flat) directory, and if the directory is recursive, duplicate names would not go into one single directory :)

Comment: Answer posted , please review

Comment: @JacobVlijm Good point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer under construction, please be patient :)**

**How this works**

Create a file named `makeDirs.sh`, copy over the script bellow into the file, save, and make script executable with `chmod +x /path/to/makeDirs.sh`

*REMEMBER TO HAVE BACKUPS BEFORE RUNNING ANY SCRIPT*

Call the script with directory on which you want to operate as command line argument. [Demo](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12962343/)

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

OPERATINGDIR="$1"
mkdir "$OPERATINGDIR/TMP"

find "$OPERATINGDIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f  | while IFS= read  FILE
do

  printf " operating on $FILE. Moving to TMP dir\n"
  mv "$FILE" "$OPERATINGDIR/TMP" 

  FULLBASENAME="$(basename "$FILE" )"
  CROPPEDBASENAME="$( basename "$FILE" | awk -F'.' '{ for(i=1;i<NF;i++) printf $i FS }' )"

  printf "Cropped basename is %s\n Full basename %s\n" "$CROPPEDBASENAME" "$FULLBASENAME"

# test if we have basename-directory made
  [ -d "$OPERATINGDIR"/"$CROPPEDBASENAME"  ] || mkdir "$OPERATINGDIR"/"$CROPPEDBASENAME" && printf "created "$OPERATINGDIR"/"$CROPPEDBASENAME" "

  printf "Moving $FILE from TMP folder to "$OPERATINGDIR"/"$CROPPEDBASENAME" \n"
  mv "$OPERATINGDIR"/TMP/"$FULLBASENAME" "$OPERATINGDIR"/"$CROPPEDBASENAME"

printf "\n\n"
done
```

Comment: Shoot I think I'm having a problem b/c the filenames are video files of the format Engineering.TV.S01E13.720p.BluRay.x264-GECKOS.mkv.part

Comment: Script didn't consider multiple dots. I'll be fixing that. Will let you know one i fix it

Comment: Done editing. Script now works on duplicate filenames as well as names with multiple dots

Comment: getting this output `find: `S01': No such file or directory
find: `720p': No such file or directory
find: `BluRay': No such file or directory
find: `x264-MIXED': No such file or directory`

Comment: @MichaelJames how are you calling the scrip ? It's supposed to be  "./makeDirs  theDirectory".

Comment: sudo bash rename.sh housestark/Videos/Engineering\ TV/Engineering\ TV\ Season\ 1\ S01\ 720p\ BluRay\ x264-MIXED\ /  I just used a different name for the bash file.  Additionally I am familiar with using scripts and the paths are correct.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30701/discussion-between-serg-and-michael-james).

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, you intend to supply a directory name as the first argument of the shell script.  Files in that directory are to be moved into subdirectories of that directory whose names are the same as the files but with extensions omitted.  In that case:

```
#!/bin/bash    
for f in "$1"/*
do
    [ -d "$f" ] && continue
    base=${f%.*}
    mkdir -p "$base"
    mv "$f" "$base/"
done
```

How it works:

- `[ -d "$f" ] && continue`

  To avoid recursion, this skips subdirectories of `$1`.
- `base=${f%.*}`

  This assigns to shell variable `base` the name of `$f` with its extension removed.  This is an example of *suffix removal*.
- `mkdir -p "$base"`

  This makes sure that the directory `$base` exists.
- `mv "$f" "$base/"`

  This moves the file to the directory.

Comment: Getting an error.  Cannot move to a subdirectory of itself.

Comment: @MichaelJames That happened with the first version that I posted.  So, I added a line, `[ -d "$f" ] && continue` to avoid that.  Please try using the code in the current version of the answer.

Comment: Shoot I think I'm having a problem b/c the filenames are video files of the format Engineering.TV.S01E13.720p.BluRay.x264-GECKOS.mkv.part.  The script isn't giving me errors but it is not doing anything either.

Comment: @MichaelJames I just tested it with that file name and it worked fine for me.  Can you provide more information?

Comment: Sry but I ran with -v and still no output besides the script.  I'm not sure why it isn't working beyond the format of the file.

Comment: @MichaelJames Please run `bash -x scriptname dirname`.  The `-x` option makes bash verbose.  That should tell us what is going on.

Comment: This is the only output I get with -x `+ for f in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -d 'housestark/Videos/Engineering TV/Engineering TV Season 1 S01 720p BluRay x264-MIXED //*' ']'
+ continue`

Comment: @MichaelJames I think that explains it.   I wrote the script assuming that you would supply the directory name as the argument.  You were supplying a glob.  Just use `bash -x scriptname dirname` without the `/*`.  Remember that the current directory is called `.`.  So, to run it on the current directory, use `bash -x scriptname .`.